# Swift Generic api response wrapper

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to make response wrapper for my api response like below

```
class ResponseModel<T> {
     var Status: String!
     var Errors: [NSDictionary]?
     var Message: String?
     var ErrorCode: NSNumber?
     var Data: T?
}
```

I tried ObjectMapper, EVReflection and MJExtension. When I use ObjectMapper "T" must be Mappable but I want to pass also String, Int etc. to "T". When I use EVReflection or MJExtension "Data" in "T" returns nil or empty for String, Int etc. but I use custom models it's working just fine.

So how should I make generic my specified values?

Comment: If you have control over your API, one option would be to wrap the `String` or `Int` versions of `T` in some object structure `{ "value": "String" }` or `{ "value": Int }`.

Another option is to have multiple properties in your `ResponseModel` object: `var StringData: String?` and `var IntData: Int?`

Presumably depending on some other property in the object, you know if you expect an Object<T>, String, or Int.  Without more details, its hard to fully understand your architecture.  Can you share more information?